# How to use docker secrets for a parameters with the same names?

Tags: docker-compose, docker-secrets

Let's say I have such case.
Two services with two sensitive values ...

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  service_1:
    image: image_A
    environment:
      SERVICE_SECRET: 1111

  service_2:
    image: image_A
    environment:
      SERVICE_SECRET: 2222
```

Now I want to hide the sensitive values by using secrets. But because the secret parameters have the sam name so I can't to do like bellow.

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  service_1:
    image: image_A
    secrets:
      - SERVICE_SECRET

  service_2:
    image: image_A
    secrets:
      - SERVICE_SECRET

secrets:
  SERVICE_SECRET:
    file: ./path/service_secret1.txt
  SERVICE_SECRET:
    file: ./path/service_secret2.txt
```

How should looks this configuration in my case?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/ in this case secrets should to use "long syntax":

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  service_1:
    image: image_A
    secrets:
      - source: SERVICE_SECRET1
      target: SERVICE_SECRET

  service_2:
    image: image_A
    secrets:
      - source: SERVICE_SECRET2
      target: SERVICE_SECRET

secrets:
  SERVICE_SECRET1:
    file: ./path/service_secret1.txt
  SERVICE_SECRET2:
    file: ./path/service_secret2.txt
```